# How to make android material design compatible with android 4

Tags: android, material-design

I have recently updated my android studio and the new one comes with material design. For Android 5.1 and above (API 21), everything works perfectly but i am receiving queries from my users on android 4.4 kitkat of the app crashing on opening it or on clicking on any item. Is it that Material design does not support below api 21. If it does support, how do i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might not be using support library:

```
compile  'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

This support lib brings a number of important material design components to all Android 2.1 or higher.

And then you have to change the code (templates and includes) to use this support elements instead of the others. Just check all the crashes you find with a device which has android version less than 5 and replace the elements with the one in the support lib.

You can find more info at https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to test your app with a device (or emulator) running the lowest Android version your app supports. That way you can detect crashes before you publish your app.

Generally, the material design libraries also work with Android 4, but there a various Support... Classes to be used when targeting old versions of Android.

When you test on old version yoi'll see exactly where the crashes happen and can take measures against.

Answer (score 0):

you can build two different layout designs in drawable. one for the lower version of SDK  and one for higher version, the app will automatically detect and show.

But if Material design, not the issue, then after checking the issue 
you can solve it using

```
// Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    // your code
} else {
    // your code 
}
Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT = 19
```

Comment: hope it helps your problem, happy coding.